# Inverted pendulum LQR controller using motor

Tags: optimal-control

In my lab, I am trying to balance an inverted pendulum using simple LQR. To balance the arm I am using a DC motor. Now I have the A,B,C,D matrices. Using those I am able to find the feedback gain 'K' using MATLAB `lqr` command. There are several parameters needed to find A,B,C,D. Among these are 3 parameters related to electrical characteristics of the DC motor: (1) motor torque constant; (2) motor back-emf constant ;(3) motor armature resistance. I have 2 DC motors. There are 2 DC motors I am using: one is 24v, 3600RPM and other is rated 12V but lesser RPM(exact RPM not known).

I have the '3' electrical characteristics mentioned above for the 12V rated motor, and using that motor i have successfully balanced the pendulum by a lots of tuning of Q,R matrices.

My problem here is that for the 24V rated motor I don't have those 3 parameters. And hence my A,B,C,D matrices cannot be found for system using 24V motor.

So my question is will those 3 parameters really affect the system matrices that much? Or since every other parameter in system remains same except those 3 when I change motor, so even if i use the 12V motor's electrical characteristics for 24v motor also, meaning the same A,B,C,D matrices, i should still be able to balance the system?

The reason I am asking this is, because LQR 'K' depends on A,B matrices of system, so if i use wrong A,B matrices then the resulting 'K' can never actually balance it.

Also NOTE: I will use 24V motor at 12V supply only since the objective requires to keep 12V as max control effort.